# Unable to upgrade from Ubuntu 22.10 - packages have been kept back: libgd-dev libgd3 libgd3:i386

Tags: ubuntu, apt, upgrade

I'm a layman when it comes to using Linux/Ubuntu. I'm on Ubuntu 22.10 unable to uprade. I tried all that I could find on internet:

```
apt update
apt upgrade
apt full-upgrade
```

Here is the log:

```
hp@hp-workstation:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.10
Release:    22.10
Codename:   kinetic


hp@hp-workstation:/etc/apt$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://download.onlyoffice.com/repo/debian squeeze InRelease
Hit:2 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu kinetic InRelease                                                                                                                                                                             
Hit:3 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                                                                                                                                                                              
Hit:4 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                
Ign:5 https://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                   
Hit:6 https://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb stable Release                                                                                                                                                                                     
Hit:7 https://repo.protonvpn.com/debian stable InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                     
Hit:9 https://cli.github.com/packages stable InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                       
Hit:10 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/edge stable InRelease                                                                                                                                                                            
Hit:11 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic InRelease                                                                                                                                                                               
Hit:12 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-updates InRelease                                                                                                                                         
Hit:13 https://apt.syncthing.net syncthing InRelease                                                                                                                   
Hit:14 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/alex-p/tesseract-ocr-devel/ubuntu kinetic InRelease
Hit:15 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease                                                                     
Hit:16 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-backports InRelease                                                          
Get:17 https://mega.nz/linux/repo/xUbuntu_22.10 ./ InRelease [2,961 B]                                      
Hit:18 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-security InRelease                                                   
Hit:19 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/christian-boxdoerfer/fsearch-stable/ubuntu kinetic InRelease
Ign:20 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/flatpak/stable/ubuntu kinetic InRelease
Hit:21 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/hluk/copyq/ubuntu kinetic InRelease
Hit:22 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/inkscape.dev/stable/ubuntu kinetic InRelease
Hit:23 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/jcfp/nobetas/ubuntu kinetic InRelease
Ign:24 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/micahflee/ppa/ubuntu kinetic InRelease
Hit:25 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Err:26 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/flatpak/stable/ubuntu kinetic Release                                                                                                                                                                
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::3e 443]
Err:27 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/micahflee/ppa/ubuntu kinetic Release                                                                                                                                                                 
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::3e 443]
Reading package lists... Done                                                                                                                                                                                                                
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-amd64/Packages' as repository 'http://download.onlyoffice.com/repo/debian squeeze InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://download.onlyoffice.com/repo/debian squeeze InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/i18n/Translation-en' as repository 'http://download.onlyoffice.com/repo/debian squeeze InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/i18n/Translation-en_IN' as repository 'http://download.onlyoffice.com/repo/debian squeeze InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/i18n/Translation-en_GB' as repository 'http://download.onlyoffice.com/repo/debian squeeze InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/dep11/Components-amd64.yml' as repository 'http://download.onlyoffice.com/repo/debian squeeze InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/dep11/icons-48x48.tar' as repository 'http://download.onlyoffice.com/repo/debian squeeze InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/dep11/icons-64x64.tar' as repository 'http://download.onlyoffice.com/repo/debian squeeze InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar' as repository 'http://download.onlyoffice.com/repo/debian squeeze InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/cnf/Commands-amd64' as repository 'http://download.onlyoffice.com/repo/debian squeeze InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Target Sources (main/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:6 and /etc/apt/sources.list:7
W: Target Sources (restricted/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:6 and /etc/apt/sources.list:7
W: Target Sources (universe/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:6 and /etc/apt/sources.list:19
W: Target Sources (multiverse/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:6 and /etc/apt/sources.list:29
W: Target Sources (main/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:12 and /etc/apt/sources.list:13
W: Target Sources (restricted/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:12 and /etc/apt/sources.list:13
W: Target Sources (universe/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:12 and /etc/apt/sources.list:21
W: Target Sources (multiverse/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:12 and /etc/apt/sources.list:31
W: Target Sources (main/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:39 and /etc/apt/sources.list:40
W: Target Sources (restricted/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:39 and /etc/apt/sources.list:40
W: Target Sources (universe/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:39 and /etc/apt/sources.list:40
W: Target Sources (multiverse/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:39 and /etc/apt/sources.list:40
W: Target Sources (main/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list:44
W: Target Sources (restricted/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list:44
W: Target Sources (universe/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list:46
W: Target Sources (multiverse/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list:48
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/flatpak/stable/ubuntu kinetic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/micahflee/ppa/ubuntu kinetic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Target Sources (main/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:6 and /etc/apt/sources.list:7
W: Target Sources (restricted/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:6 and /etc/apt/sources.list:7
W: Target Sources (universe/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:6 and /etc/apt/sources.list:19
W: Target Sources (multiverse/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:6 and /etc/apt/sources.list:29
W: Target Sources (main/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:12 and /etc/apt/sources.list:13
W: Target Sources (restricted/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:12 and /etc/apt/sources.list:13
W: Target Sources (universe/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:12 and /etc/apt/sources.list:21
W: Target Sources (multiverse/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:12 and /etc/apt/sources.list:31
W: Target Sources (main/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:39 and /etc/apt/sources.list:40
W: Target Sources (restricted/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:39 and /etc/apt/sources.list:40
W: Target Sources (universe/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:39 and /etc/apt/sources.list:40
W: Target Sources (multiverse/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:39 and /etc/apt/sources.list:40
W: Target Sources (main/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list:44
W: Target Sources (restricted/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list:44
W: Target Sources (universe/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list:46
W: Target Sources (multiverse/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list:48



hp@hp-workstation:~$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  libgd-dev libgd3 libgd3:i386
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.





hp@hp-workstation:~$ sudo apt install libgd-dev libgd3 libgd3:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgd3 : Depends: libavif13 (>= 0.9.3) but it is not installable
          Breaks: libgd3:i386 (!= 2.3.3-9+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) but 2.3.3-6+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 is to be installed
 libgd3:i386 : Breaks: libgd3 (!= 2.3.3-6+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) but 2.3.3-9+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.



hp@hp-workstation:~$ sudo apt-get --with-new-pkgs upgrade  libgd-dev libgd3 libgd3:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgd3 : Depends: libavif13 (>= 0.9.3) but it is not installable
          Breaks: libgd3:i386 (!= 2.3.3-9+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) but 2.3.3-6+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 is to be installed
 libgd3:i386 : Breaks: libgd3 (!= 2.3.3-6+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) but 2.3.3-9+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 is to be installed
E: Broken packages





hp@hp-workstation:~$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  libgd-dev libgd3 libgd3:i386
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
```

All I want is to get out of this 22.10 but 3 package kept back is preventing me to do the upgrade. I've copy pasted every command I could find (with half-baked understanding) on the topic nothing worked. Hence I asked the question.

They said that its [offtopic on Ask Ubutu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1485931/)

**Update:**

```
(base) hp@hp-workstation:~$ grep -r ondrej /etc/apt
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ondrej-ubuntu-php-kinetic.list:deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/ jammy main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ondrej-ubuntu-php-kinetic.list:# deb-src https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/ kinetic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ondrej-ubuntu-php-kinetic.list.save:deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/ jammy main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ondrej-ubuntu-php-kinetic.list.save:# deb-src https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/ kinetic main
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your ultimate goal is to upgrade to 23.04, the best approach here is to disable the offending PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt update
```

If that doesn’t work, delete the repository configuration file:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ondrej-ubuntu-php-kinetic.list
sudo apt update
```

You should then find that you no longer have any upgrade candidates.

Comment: What care should I take in future to avoid such problems? don't add PPAs?

Comment: As a general rule, yes, avoid adding PPAs; and if you do, be willing to remove them if necessary during upgrades.